# Logistic Regression Model returning same output for all inputs

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, numpy

I made a simple linear regression model with a simple .csv dataset that had 2 categories.

For reference, the dataset looks like a larger version of this

[image: What the dataset looks like]

Basically, it is a hobby classification dataset having two categories,

`'Name' and 'Category'.`

Now, I made a Logistic Regression model to classify the Hobbies based on their name.

Therefore, I took 'Name' as X and 'Category' as y.

Here is the simple code to train the model :

```py
X = data['Name']
X.values.reshape(1, -1)
y = data['Category']
y.values.reshape(1, -1)

model = LogisticRegression()

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

X_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train.ravel())

X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(256, -1)
y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(256, -1)

model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Now, I made a simple list of 3 Names with diff categories for the purpose of testing.

```py
my_test = ['Sociology', 'Acting', 'Coding']

my_test = label_encoder.fit_transform(my_test)

my_test = np.array(my_test).reshape(3, -1)

model.predict(my_test)
```

But, this is the output

```py
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the same output for all inputs I'm putting. Why is this happening ?

Comment: You should include your example data as text in the question, not image. Thanks.

Comment: Why the result is a problem ? what is your expected output ? What is your model accuracy ?

Comment: @malo All 3 inputs have different categories

Comment: So, it should return 3 duiff outputs

Comment: so what is your model accuracy ?
LabelEncoder is only for target / Y, as this is written in scikit documentation. For X data you should use OneHotEncoder.

Comment: oh ok. I'll try that

Comment: It isn't working

Comment: The model accuracy is around 71%

Comment: I see two points which could be a probleme in your case: it is not clear if you have enough data in your data set. And also this problem seems to be solvable with a simple table or dict lookup. It does not seem to be a good use case for ML.